# what is the knowledge i have to know to make centrelized DB in PC and access it via internet using java application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, centralized

i want to make centralized MySQL DB in PC like server , 
and manipulate it via internet using java application .

i have already learn MySQL and java ,but i can't reach which i want.

what is the knowledge i have to know to make this ?

some detailed description about my project :

i work at a community  as a data administrator which have many activities.
in each activity there is many clients and workers deal with this activity.
i have a team work with me , for each activity has a 1 data team member responsible for it (entering data , updating , making reports).
 we make all this with MS Excel,but the data is increasing and i can't manage it.

so i think to make a program help me to manage all these data , but we need one database to hold these data not many database, to union it and every one can work at home.

so, i need some one refers to tutorials and books to make this program .

Comment: So you are asking [how to make/use a connection to a remote MySQL DB in Java?

Comment: You're going to want a webservice framework, one of the most popular current ones is [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/).  Yeah, Excel isn't a real database, that's not going to work long term

Comment: The correct answer to this question is to learn web application development, which could be the subject of several dozen different books, or several semesters of undergraduate-level education.  This is not really an appropriate question for SO, which is focused on specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: yes  ghbarratt 
I am asking [how to make/use a connection to a remote MySQL DB in Java?

Comment: thanks for help  Jim Garrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web application would be a solution for your problems.

For that you would need to know how to configure and work with a server like JBoss for example. Further you'll be needing servlets or some mvc framework like spring for example. There are so many possibilities; sounds to me like you should find someone who can do this for you.